# Access NodeJS demo application in AWS Lightsail outside Localhost

Tags: node.js, amazon-lightsail

I am test driving AWS Lightsail for one of my NodeJS experiments. Installed NodeJS using SSH on the server and ran a demo program(see below). I can see the output "Hello World" from the SSH terminal with the command " curl localhost:3000". But when I access it from outside the network, using my web browser in my home PC, with the Public IP address and port number 3000, it says "This site can't be reached" I've forwarded the port 3000 on the server side.

Anything I am missing?

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
```

Comment: Are you allowing traffic to port 3000 of your Lightsail instance? This is usually configured by security groups which allows access to specified port. This is a security mechanism most cloud providers have. They by default do not allow traffic to any port other than port 22 that is for ssh. Try checking if port 3000 is open or not. But this is not at all a best practice as traffic should be routed only from port 80(for http) or 443(for https).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't pass on host to `.listen`, server will run on all interfaces including 0.0.0.0. But you are running server to listen on localhost only.Change `.listen` like this:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000);
```

You will also have to add Inbound traffic rule(Firewall) to open port 3000 to access the server over the internet as your server running on port 3000.

1. Click on an instance and then select networking option
2. Go to firewall section and click on "add another" as shown in below pic
   [image]

3. Click on save and then you should be able to access a server with http://IP:3000.
4. If you want to access your server without specifying a port in URL then you have to configure 'Nginx reverse proxy'. Also, port 80(for http) and port 443(https) should be allowed through a firewall.

Comment: For me the step 2 was totally enough

Comment: What if I want to connect through https?

Answer (score 1):

If you `.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");` listen on `127.0.0.1`, it only allows `local` machine to access the server. You need `.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");` to allow any ip address to access the server.